# Is operator && strict in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, logical-operators, strictness

For example, I have an operation `fnB :: a -> Bool` that makes no sense until `fnA :: Bool` returns `False`. In C I may compose these two operations in one `if` block:

```
if( fnA && fnB(a) ){ doSomething; }
```

and C will guarantee that `fnB` will not execute until `fnA` returns false.

But Haskell is lazy, and, generally, there is no guarantee what operation will execute first, until we don't use `seq`, `$!`, or something else to make our code strict. Generally, this is what we need to be happy. But using `&&` operator, I would expect that `fnB` will not be evaluated until `fnA` returns its result. Does Haskell provide such a guarantee with `&&`? And will Haskell evaluate `fnB` even when `fnA` returns False?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The function `(&&)` is strict in its second argument only if its first argument is `True`.  It is always strict in its first argument.  This strictness / laziness is what guarantees the order of evaluation.

So it behaves exactly like C.  The difference is that in Haskell, `(&&)` is an ordinary function.  In C, this would be impossible.

> But Haskell is lazy, and, generally, there are no guarantee what operation will execute first, until we don't use seq, $!, or something else to make our code strict.

This is not correct.  The truth is deeper.

**Crash course in strictness:**

We know `(&&)` is strict in its first parameter because:

```
⊥ && x = ⊥
```

Here, ⊥ is something like `undefined` or an infinite loop (⊥ is pronounced "bottom").  We also know that `(False &&)` is non-strict in its second argument:

```
False && ⊥ = False
```

It can't possibly evaluate its second argument, because its second argument is ⊥ which can't be evaluated.  However, the function `(True &&)` is strict in its second argument, because:

```
True && ⊥ = ⊥
```

So, we say that `(&&)` is always strict in its first argument, and strict in its second argument only when the first argument is `True`.

**Order of evaluation:**

For `(&&)`, its strictness properties are enough to guarantee order of execution.  That is not always the case.  For example, `(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int` is always strict in both arguments, so either argument can be evaluated first.  However, you can only tell the difference by catching exceptions in the `IO` monad, or if you use an `unsafe` function.

Comment: Actually, it's never strict in the second argument. It returns that without evaluating it.

Comment: @larsmans: Actually, any function which returns a value without evaluating it is *by definition* strict in that argument.  For example, the function `id` is always strict in its argument.

Comment: This answer seems to assume sequential evaluation. An implementation could legitimately evaluate both arguments in parallel, as long as the first one gets its share of resources and exceptions from the second are handled properly. This would be a *surprising* implementation, but a legal one.

Comment: @dfeuer: Okay, if we're going to be pedantic about it… First, the question is specifically asking about evaluation order, so we must talk about it in order to answer the question.  Second, if we are talking about evaluation order with respect to pure Haskell semantics, we can say that since evaluating ⊥ is not possible, `False && ⊥` must not evaluate ⊥, so it must evaluate `False` first or else it would not know that it is not supposed to evaluate ⊥.  So it is not possible to evaluate `False && ⊥` in parallel.  You can write a parallel shared memory program which gives the same result, though.

Comment: @FredFoo - technically, Haskell doesn't allow 'returning a value without evaluating it'; `&&` *tail calls* its second argument when the first is `True`.

Answer (score 5):

As noted by others, naturally `(&&)` is strict in one of its arguments.  By the standard definition it's strict in its first argument.  You can use `flip` to flip the semantics.

As an additional note:  Note that the arguments to `(&&)` cannot have side effects, so there are only two reasons why you would want to care whether `x && y` is strict in `y`:

- Performance: If `y` takes a long time to compute.
- Semantics: If you expect that `y` can be bottom.

Comment: I like your comments about side-effects.  If you don't want to care about the order, it is possible to define a truly symmetric and: ``a &=& b = (a && b) `unamb` (b && a)``

Comment: The arguments to `(&&)` can have side-effects if they use `unsafePerformIO`, but then you get what you ask for!

Comment: @luqui Indeed, the `Data.Unamb.pand` function is defined as exactly that (modulo a few layers of abstraction).

Answer (score 1):

> Haskell is lazy, and, generally, there is no guarantee what operation will execute first

Not quite.  Haskell is *pure* (except for `unsafePerformIO` and the implementation of `IO`), and there is no way to *observe* which operation will execute first (except for `unsafePerformIO` and the implementation of `IO`).  The order of execution simply *does not matter* for the result.

`&&` has a 9-value truth table, including the cases where one or both arguments are `undefined`, and it defines the operation exactly:

```
a           b           a && b
True        True        True
True        False       False
True        undefined   undefined
False       True        False
False       False       False
False       undefined   False
undefined   True        undefined
undefined   False       undefined
undefined   undefined   undefined
```

As long as the implementation follows that table, it's allowed to execute things in any order it wants.

(If you study the table, you'll notice that there's no way for a *sequential* implementation to follow it unless it executes `a` first, then `b` iff `a` is True.  But Haskell implementations are not required to be sequential!  An implementation is always *allowed* to kick of execution of `b` whenever it wants; your only guarantee is that, according to the table, the result of executing `b` can only impact your program when `a` is True.)

(Note that 'laziness' is the only way to write a *function* with a truth table like the above at all; in a language like C or ML, all five of the lines with `undefined` in either argument would be force to have `undefined` as the result, where in Haskell (and in C, because `&&` is built in to the C language) one of the lines can have `False` as the result instead.)

Answer (score -1):

I believe it works the way you expect; evaluate the RHS iff the LHS evaluates to True.  However, assuming the RHS has no side-effects, how would you know (or care)?

Edit:  I guess the RHS could be `undefined`, and then you would care...

Comment: It's not undefined. The Haskell Report gives a full listing of the `Prelude` which serves as a spec. And it's perfectly alright to care about this, since `(&&)` can be used to combine a simple & quick test with one that requires intensive computation.

Comment: I meant that the RHS could be undefined, and then you would care if it was evaluated